# How to automatically resize the remaining elements after adding a BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, containers, layout-manager, border-layout

I added a simple `statusBar` to the application. It works normally, adjusts its size depending on the resolution.

Only that by adding this status bar, suddenly other elements in the application, such as text fields or table, lost this ability to "adjust elements".

If we remove these three lines in the code, I will lose the status bar, but the other elements will adapt as I want.

```
  Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
  contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  contentPane.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

How can I make both `statusBar` and the other elements adjust to size?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Menu {
    static void MenuBar() throws SQLException, IOException {

       
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();


    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.setSize(1600, 1000);
    frame.setVisible(true); //If I delete any more, all the content will disappear
    frame.setContentPane(new Recipe().Main);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JStatusBar statusBar = new JStatusBar();
    JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel("App");
    statusBar.setLeftComponent(leftLabel);


    final JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
    timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    statusBar.addRightComponent(timeLabel);

    contentPane.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: The problem is because you are adding a new `BorderLayout`. Remove this line and use the DEFAULT `BorderLayout` that comes already in the JFrame's content pane. Spend some time reading the [Oracle Tutorials on Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to get a glimpse of what Layout Managers come with default with different Swing components. This should eliminate this sort of questions in the future.

Comment: `frame.pack();` should be done *after* all components are added, and `frame.setVisible(true);` should be last. I don't agree with using the default layout. I'll *always* add a `JPanel` to the content pane, with a layout explicitly set & add everything else (including other panels) to that content panel.  **BTW:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. 2) Provide ASCII art or drawing of the intended layout at the minimum size and when dragged larger.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do the same thing (sometimes). But, to me is overkill to add more containers to my Swing application only to set up the same layout manager that already comes with the default contents pane. That said, I can see the benefit of being explicit to show your real intent. I do this from time to time, and I recognize to be a beneficial practice when you are learning. Good point, though.

Comment: @hfontanez *"the same layout manager that already comes with the default contents pane"* Were you developing in Java Swing way back around Java 1.5 when the default layout of a frame changed from `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout`? It 'broke' a lot of code, so now I tend not to trust default layouts at all. Coding a GUI in a `JPanel` also gives us the option to put it in a `JFrame` .. or a `JWindow`, a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`, as a card in a `CardLayout`, a `JDesktopPane`, a `JSplitPane` or .. Once the design is in a panel, it can be displayed in *many* different ways.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I used to work on Swing apps back in the 1.4.2 days and migrated Swing apps from 1.4.2 to Java 5. Then to Java 7 and 8. And, although I am aware of some of the issues you mentioned, I never really had any major issues with my applications. Only exception was an issue I encountered with the LAF for a very specific case. As I stated in my previous comment, I sometimes (should've said _often_) do the same thing you do.

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson, I tried as you wrote, that is I moved `frame.pack;` and `frame.setVisible(true);` to the last line of code after adding the components and I don't see much effect, except that the size of the components got smaller ((I changed the code so you could see if I understood what you wrote)

Comment: Hi @hfontanez So I should remove ` contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`, but I'm not sure what you mean by replacing it with using the default BorderLayout

Comment: *"I changed the code so you could see if I understood what you wrote"* Yes, that's what I meant. Time to move on to an MRE and some drawings of the intended GUI.

Comment: @JJJokers223 The `JFrame` content pane already gets instantiated with the same Layout Manager.

Comment: @hfontanez So I understand that JFrame contains the same Layout Manager as Border Layout. But if I remove `contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` and try to call the same operations as for BorderLayout it won't work after all.

Comment: @JJJokers223 as for the "resize" issue, I will update my answer shortly...

Comment: @JJJokers223 I updated my answer to address resizing. I hope my "rambling" is clear enough. Also, I colored the panels added to the different regions to easily illustrate how the Layout Manager itself sizes these panels to occupy a certain region of the content pane _even though I never defined the size I wanted for each panel_. The layout manager decides this based on the size of the frame and adjusts the size of the panel on that sort of space distribution; where the _CENTER_ region takes the most space and the other ones form a sort of "border frame" around it. If I "pack" the frame....

Comment: ...everything gets compacted because these panels are "dimensionless." That is, I never set any preferred sizes, or minimum sizes and they don't contain any internal components that restrict the size of the frame EXCEPT for the `JLabel` objects I added to the content pane. If you uncomment the call to `pack()`, you will see that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a proof of concept, I modified your code slightly to show you what I meant:

```
public class Menu {
    void MenuBar() throws SQLException, IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Main Menu"));

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.add(new JLabel("CENTER"));

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        south.add(new JLabel("SOUTH"));
        south.setBackground(Color.green);
        JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel("App");
//    statusBar.setLeftComponent(leftLabel);

        final JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
        timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//    statusBar.addRightComponent(timeLabel);

        contentPane.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JPanel east = new JPanel();
        east.add(new JLabel("EAST"));
        east.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        contentPane.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        JPanel west = new JPanel();
        west.add(new JLabel("WEST"));
        west.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        contentPane.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel north = new JPanel();
        north.add(new JLabel("NORTH"));
        north.setBackground(Color.orange);
        contentPane.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//      frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                try {
                    menu.MenuBar();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code above produces the following result (not calling `pack()` to respect the set size of the frame)

[image]

As you can see from the code above, I am not adding a **new** `BorderLayout` to the frame's content pane because it already contains one by default when you instantiate the content pane via the `JFrame`. I am simply using it and setting the components in the different regions designated by this layout manager.

### Resizing the frame

Different layout managers enforce different behaviors during a resize event. It all depends on the layout manager. For instance, `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default. Depending on the size when the panel renders, you will see components inside a `JPanel` arranged from left to right. When there is no more space (defined by the bounds of the panel), you will see components arranged on a "row" below the first components. This means that, if you reduce the panel's width during a resize, you should see components wrapped and stacked one on top of others inside this panel. In contrast, if you use a `GridLayout` and resize the panel, the behavior is totally different. You can even have restrictions to set a minimum and/or maximum sizes to constraint much much or how little a component should resize and a preferred size attribute which is different to the "size" attribute of a container when "no layout manager" is preferred. This is called "**Absolute Positioning**" and it is done when you want full control of the actual (*x, y*) coordinates where the components should be placed and the layout manager is set to ***null***. Of course, this is not preferable. It is always better (in my opinion) to delegate this responsibility to the various layout managers that comes with Java Swing, or write one of your own (writing one might be easier said than done). I said all that to say the same thing I posted on the comments section:

> Spend some time reading the Oracle Tutorials on Layout Managers to get a glimpse of what Layout Managers come by default with different Swing components.

This will also help you understand what behavior to expect when (for instance) a resize event occurs and the things you need to do in the code to adjust this behavior to suit your needs. For example, if you need to create a checkers or chess application, it is obvious you will need a container with a `GridLayout` manager. But it is up to you to tweak it to define min and max size, preferred size, etc.

Also, something very important mentioned by Andrew Thompson... you need to know WHEN to make calls to certain methods. He specifically mentioned when to call `pack()` and `setVisible()`. Little things like that (are not really little) can make a difference.